# Macro for copying row for last year, insert copied cells in row beneath, then change year to current

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large datasheet ("Data") with several houndred rows with years in the first column (Eg 31.12.2013) and various data in the following columns.

I've tried to make a macro that goes through column A and finds every cell containing 31.12.2013 and which does not have a cell containing 31.12.2014 beneath it. For every time it does it should copy the entire row, insert the copied cells in a new row beneath it, and change the date from 31.12.2013 to 31.12.2014.

Since this is the first time I've tried making a macro I have no clue what I'm doing. This is what I got after mixing some code I found online and some code from the built in recorder, hopefully someone can make something that actually does anything:

```
    Sub Nyttaarsregnskap()

Dim searchSheet As Worksheet
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

Set searchSheet = Sheets("Data")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


searchSheet.Activate
lastRow = searchSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


For currentRow = 1 To lastRow
    If InStr(LCase(searchSheet.Cells(currentRow, "A")), "12/31/2013") > 0 Then
        If Not InStr(LCase(searchSheet.Cells(currentRow + 1, "A")), "12/31/2014") > 0 Then
            searchSheet.Rows(currentRow & ":" & currentRow).Copy
            Cells(currentRow + 1, "A").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Cells(currentRow + 1, "A").FormulaR1C1 = "12/31/2014"
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End If
    End If
Next currentRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
Sub Nyttaarsregnskap()

    Dim searchSheet As Worksheet
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set searchSheet = Sheets("Data")

    With searchSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For currentRow = lastRow To 1 Step -1
            If Format(.Cells(currentRow, "A"), "mm/dd/yyyy") = Format("12/31/2013", "mm/dd/yyyy") Then
                If Not Format(.Cells(currentRow + 1, "A"), "mm/dd/yyyy") = Format("12/31/2014", "mm/dd/yyyy") Then
                    .Range(currentRow + 1 & ":" & currentRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    .Rows(currentRow & ":" & currentRow).Copy .Cells(currentRow + 1, "A")
                    .Cells(currentRow + 1, "A").FormulaR1C1 = "12/31/2014"
                End If
            End If
        Next currentRow
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It's hard to describe exactly what happens when I run this macro. It seems to copy and insert rows, but it also deletes (or overwrites?) other rows, and jumbles up the order the rows previously were in. Also, it doesn't change the date of the new row to 2014.

Comment: It doesn't delete anything. It just add new row in case when current row has `"12/31/2013"` and next row **hasn't** "12/31/2014". And then add in new row "12/31/2014". Is it what you want?

Comment: It seems to work for some rows (the first row anyway), but for most instances it jumbles to rows up and when I sort them in ascending order again the copied values for 2014 are not the same as for 2013. One row which was the only instance of it kind wasn't duplicated at all, it just changed its year to 2014. Quite strange.

Comment: maybe you have some formulas in this rows and need to do PasteSpecial-> PasteValues instead just Paste?

Comment: When I do this manually I select the row (Shift+Space), copy it (CMD+C), move down one row and insert copied cells (Ctrl+"+"), which works perfectly apart from taking its time, so I assume that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: It seemed to help, though it deleted atleast one single row instance. Sadly I can't use PasteValues anyway, because I need to keep some vlookups and other functions.

Comment: Ah, no. The macro stopped before the end of the rows, probably because the amount of rows increased as the macro ran. Can it be fixed?